# Issue in parsing JSON String

Tags: java, json

My json string looks like,

```
{
    "userList" : {
        "user" : [{
                "Id" : "33",
                "userId" : "raji2",
                "customerId" : "35",
                "username" : "raji2",
                "status" : "1",
                "locked" : "0",
                "customAttributes" : "{\"uiPageId\":\"\",\"uiPageName\":\"\",\"uiPageViewMode\":\"Normal\"}",
                "addressList" : {
                    "address" : ""
                },
                "contactList" : {
                    "contact" : {
                        "contactno" : "+919526346097",
                        "email" : "raji@gmail.com"
                    }
                },
                "roleList" : {
                    "roleId" : "7"
                },
                "privilegeList" : {
                    "privilegeId" : ["1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27"]
                },
                "entityList" : {
                    "entityId" : ""
                }
            }, {
                "Id" : "34",
                "userId" : "raji3",
                "customerId" : "35",
                "username" : "raji3",
                "status" : "1",
                "locked" : "0",
                "customAttributes" : "{\"uiPageId\":\"\",\"uiPageName\":\"\",\"uiPageViewMode\":\"Normal\"}",
                "addressList" : {
                    "address" : ""
                },
                "contactList" : {
                    "contact" : {
                        "contactno" : "+919526346097",
                        "email" : "raji@gmail.com"
                    }
                },
                "roleList" : {
                    "roleId" : "7"
                },
                "privilegeList" : {
                    "privilegeId" : ["1", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27"]
                },
                "entityList" : {
                    "entityId" : ""
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

When I try to parse this using the sample given below and trying to take email or customerId,the data is coming as null,
The code snippet I tried is:

```
    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(data);
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
    System.out.println(jsonObject);
    String x=(String) jsonObject.get("customerId");
    System.out.println("Check Data"+x);
```

I used simple json library.
I am getting null response.

Comment: Uhm, `"customAttributes"` is a JSON Object embedded as a _string_? Meh?

Comment: Which specific library are you using? Which customerId are you trying to retrieve? All of them?

Comment: @Jahed org.json.simple,all of them

Answer (score 4):

As other commenters have said, you can't access "customerId" directly from the root element. You have to go

```
root -> userList -> user -> user[0] -> customerId
```

The following code accomplishes this

```
JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(data);
System.out.println(obj);
JSONObject userList = (JSONObject) obj.get("userList");
JSONArray user = (JSONArray) userList.get("user");
JSONObject userObj = (JSONObject) user.get(0);
String customerId = (String) userObj.get("customerId");
System.out.println("Check Data " + customerId);
```

Because each user object has a customerId property, you must select which user object you want to use. If you wanted you use your second user object, you would put `user.get(1);` on the fifth line.

**EDIT** To get the customerId for each user, replace the last three lines with a loop:

```
JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(data);
System.out.println(obj);
JSONObject userList = (JSONObject) obj.get("userList");
JSONArray user = (JSONArray) userList.get("user");
for (Object userObj : user) {
    JSONObject userJSONObject = (JSONObject) userObj;
    String customerId = (String) userJSONObject.get("customerId");
    System.out.println("Check Data " + customerId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks,Finally it worked,but I am interested in getting all customerId's of users

Comment: Replacing the last three lines with a simple loop should accomplish that. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I am not using your library, but I guess you will need to get the "userList" field first, and then get the "user" array and iterate over JSONObjects in the array to get their respective "customerId".

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do parsing 2 times.
below code will not work.

jsonObject.get("userList").get("user");

try to access inner most element using by one by one.